# No network capabiity on dell vostro 1000

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 14.04, ethernet

I just had a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04 and i have no network connectivity, i have a wifi capable computer, but there is no wifi connectivity, and the ethernet is not functioning either. I suspect missing drivers, but i don't know where to get them.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless and ethernet devices. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: lspci -nn. Pick out those two devices and add the details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had same case and now I can connect.

I opened terminal with alt+ctrl+t

> gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

found following line

*SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTRS{address}=="$MAC", NAME="eth0"*

it was longer and I shortened it. Then copied $MAC (Mac address) and saved the file.
then I right-clicked network icon on top bar and opened *Edit connections*
then clicked add. Ethernet. Pasted $MAC to both MAC address boxes. Saved. Connected cable. It worked.

PS: $MAC is your cards mac address, do not touch it.

If it will not work, you may visit following links for driver installation:

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2233376

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1113779